# How do I add two outlines to text in CSS

Tags: html, css

Alright so, I've recently created a short CSS code for Logos. My problem is: Adding a double outline. Is it possible?

Here's my current CSS:

```
.green {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#8CE06E, #61964E); /* Gradient colors: Top to Bottom */
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px 61964E /* Outline weight and color */
  -webkit-background-clip: text; 
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 43px;
  font-family: Luckiest Guy;
  text-align: center;
}
```

As you can see, there is one outline (Line 2):

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px 61964E /* Outline weight and color */
```

I'd like to know if I can add two outlines. The first one would be white, and the second one would be green (because the main text is green). So, it'd be Text - Outline 1 - Outline 2

Example:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a pseudo element for green with the other border color, .green:before? Check this article out, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/

Comment: @small you do realize that the article you linked is related to layout elements?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible but, in some browsers, there is a new CSS module called CSS shapes. However, it only works in Chrome, Safari and Opera at this time and its description is too broad as an answer here (and mostly cause I wouldn't know how without some study).

Google for "CSS Shapes" and you should find more than enough instruction on creating what you want.

Comment: I don't really understand how shapes could help me, unless you're suggesting I create a custom CSS shape around my text to take the form of a double outline?

Answer (score 0):

The only way this could be possible is if you were talking about boxes (divs) in CSS.